# comparing two values from the input field in c:if tag of jstl

Tags: validation, input, jstl

I have two input field through which I select date and time.Now I want to show that startdate should be always less than enddate.If it is not, then then error message should be displayed showing "enddate has to be greater" .The code for input fields is

```
<input id="startdate" type="text" size="25" name="startdate" 

onclick="javascript:NewCal('startdate','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>

<input id="enddate" type="text" size="25" name="enddate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('enddate','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)" >
<a>
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date">
</a>
<c:if test="${enddate < startdate}">
<c:out value="Endate date should be greater than start date"></c:out> </c:if>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>

</form>
```

I have tried it with tag of jstl but its not working.If I select enddate less than startdate, then no error message is shown.
What I'm doing wrong.**Can't I use the id of input field in tag of JSTL?**

**EDIT-1**
Screen Sort after filling form is
[image]

The calender appears when I click on the textfield.

Comment: please don not mess up jstl with javascript. JSTL works from server to client side and javacript works on client side

Comment: @Md.SharifulIslam ,Then how to put check on enddate i.e. **how to ensure that start date should be less than endadate**?

Comment: You can check both way- either server side or either client side? try any one

Comment: @Md.SharifulIslam,If I want to do at client side ,how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:-

modify this line:

```
<form onsubmit="date_comapare()">
<input id="startdate" type="text" size="25" name="startdate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('startdate','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)" >
<a><img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>

<input id="enddate" type="text" size="25" name="enddate" onclick="javascript:NewCal('enddate','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)" >
<a><img src="images/cal.gif" width="10" height="10" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

you may format your datepicker like this: **Mon, 09 Mar 2015 09:28:26 GMT**

javascript:-

```
function date_comapare()
{

   var d1=document.getElementIdBy("startdate").value; // start date
   var d2=document.getElementIdBy("enddate").value; //end date

   if(new Date(d2).valueOf() < new Date(d1).valueOf())
   {
      alert("Endate date should be greater than start date");  // handle  your error validation here
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: I defined javascript in <script></script>tag with in head .But its not working.When I enter enddate less than start date and when I click submit ,no alert message is shown.

Comment: can you show me a screenshot after filling your form ?

Comment: what does this function do? NewCal('startdate','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)

Comment: please see my screenshot